# dragula js: how to limit the number of elements in droparea?

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop, dragula

I have such a drag-and-drop problem. I've used this the library of dragula. I want to limit the number of elements going to the drop-area to two. Like this:

- if the number of elements is less than two in drop-area allow to add
  a new element from draggable;
- if there are two elements in drop-area, the user can only return one of
  the elements from drop-area to the draggable and then replace it with another one

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/bevacqua/dragula/master/dist/dragula.js"></script>
<style>
#chart, #chart tr {
    border: solid 3px;
    width: 1000px;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: "Almarai";
    font-size: 20px;
}
#chart {
    position: relative;
    left: 200px;
}
#chart #drop-area {
    height: 100px;
}
.gu-mirror {
  position: fixed !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  z-index: 9999 !important;
  padding: 1em;
}
.gu-hide {
  display: none !important;
}
.gu-unselectable {
  user-select: none !important;
}
.gu-transit {
  opacity: 0;
}
.gu-mirror {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table id="chart">
<tr>
<td id="drop-area">
</td>
</tr>
</table><br>
<div id="draggable">
<div id="a1">option 1</div>
<div id="a2">option 2</div>
<div id="a3">option 3</div>
<div id="a4">option 4</div>
  <script>
  function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

dragula([$('draggable'), $('drop-area')], {
  revertOnSpill: true
});
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```